# How to disable live shell session command history under AIX 5-6?

Tags: command-history, aix

It's okay that there are history files logging the commands that has been used. That't not the problem. The problem is that when 2 admins are logged in to an AIX server then it could be bad:

If admin #A uses

```
rm FILENAME
```

then if admin #B hits the up arrow he gets the

```
rm FILENAME
```

command which is not a very good thing. So how can the termial be forced to only write the command history if the ssh session ended? (UPDATE#2: or solution could be that that each session has it's uniq command history, and thus we can't see each others command, only when they sign out for ex.)

UPDATE#1

```
4:root@SERVER:/root # echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/ksh
4:root@SERVER:/root # oslevel -s
6100-05-01-1016
4:root@SERVER:/root #
```

Comment: Just for the record the behavior you are attributing to Linux is a `bash` feature other shells can behave differently.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: which shell and version of shell are you using?

Comment: question updated, but there are machines with several oslevels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your admin's use `sudo`, instead of just `su`'ing to `root`, they'll retain their own command history.

Alternatively, you can use ksh's `HISTFILE` variable to set the filename for the history.  Add,

```
HISTFILE=~/.hist$$
```

to root's `.profile`. That'll generate a unique history file for every session, but you'll need some way to housekeep them.